# Can't restart activity after clicking on notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

When app receives message from GCM, it shows notification.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("TheBriefPost")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

When I click on notification, app opens activity but not restarting. What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be related to the flags of the Intent/Pending Intent

According to [PendingIntent in Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)
In the Pending Intent you sent a flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this
>   new Intent.

I guess in your case you need to use PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, the current one should be canceled before generating a new one.

Accodring to [Activity in Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
In the Activity you set the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

I guess here you need to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.

Comment: It helped. Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

> app opens activity but not restarting

It should not be restarted. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is "*If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.*"

Why you want it restarted? To handle intent data? If so, implement `onNewIntent()` in your activity.

Comment: I am sending GCM message to device, in order to inform "new events available". If user clicks, activity should be restarted, so it loads data from scratch. That's why I need to restart activity. Is there anyway to do this?